# Multi Level JSON for Laravel View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on Laravel Framework.
Trying to fetch the product details by joining other tables.
3 Tables are there:
   1. product
   2. category
   3. sub_category

Controller

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $sliders = Slider::all();
    $promotions = Promotion::all();
    $categories = Categories::with('SubCategory')->get();
    $products = Product::with('Category')->with('SubCategory')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(10)->get();
    $hotdealproducts = HotDeal::with('Product')->get();
    $featuredproducts = Product::with('Category')->with('SubCategory')->where('is_featured', 1)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(10)->get();
    $testimonials = Testimonial::all();

     return view('index', [
                          'sliders' =>  $sliders,
                          'promotions' =>  $promotions,
                          'categories' =>  $categories,
                          'products' => $products,
                          'hotdealproducts' => $hotdealproducts,
                          'featuredproducts' => $featuredproducts,
                          'testimonials' => $testimonials,
                        ]);

    // return $products;
  }
}
```

JSON for $products

```
    [{
      "id":3,
      "product_name":"Floral Print Buttoned",
      "product_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. ",
      "category":{
          "id":1,
          "category_name":"Clothing",
          "icon":"fa fa-shopping-bag"
       },
      "sub_category":{
         "id":1,
         "category_id":1,
         "sub_category":"Dresses"
      },
      "general_price":2000,
      "offer_price":1500,
      "cover_image":"1.jpg",
      "is_featured":"1",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null
    }]
```

In View, i am trying fetch the child JSON but getting error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
 .....
  @foreach ($product->category as $category)
     <a href="{{$category->category_name}}">
       <img src="" alt="">
     </a>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

While using `{{$product->category}}` id is showing.
Can someone please solve this problem, I checked all the stacks but I did not find any correct answer.

Comment: `foreach ((array) $product->category as $category) {
 // ...
 }`

Comment: What is (array) ??

Comment: Object property `category` of $product is an object, not the array. You can simply access it like `$product->category->category_name`

Comment: Still getting the same error ````Trying to get property of non-object````

Comment: Are you passing a JSON String or a `json_decode(JSON String)` to the view?

Comment: I think some of the products doesn't have categories put it like this `@foreach (@$product->category as $category)`

Comment: @Vipertecpro ````Invalid Argument Supplied ````

Comment: @RiggsFolly JSON String

Comment: So do a `json_decode()` on the string before passing it to the view. Otherwise its just a string

Comment: Is this resolved or you still need follow up ?